# Convert seconds to date and time in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame with a column containing seconds and I would like to convert the column to date and  time and save the file with a column containing the date and time .I Have a column like this in seconds

```
time
2384798300  
1500353475  
7006557825
1239779541
1237529231
```

I was able to do it but by only inserting the number of seconds that i want to convert with the following code:

`datetime.fromtimestamp(1238479969).strftime("%A, %B %d, %Y %I:%M:%S")`

`output : Tuesday, March 31, 2009 06:12:49'`

What i want to get is the conversion of the whole column,I tried this :

`datetime.fromtimestamp(df['time']).strftime("%A, %B %d, %Y %I:%M:%S")` but I can not get it, any help of how i can do it will be appreciated.

Comment: is it a timedelta? are they seconds since epoch or something else? a standard `pd.to_datetime(df['time'],unit='s')` will work but i doubt the validity of the data as its returning 2045 and 2192 once its a datetime object you can use `strftime` methods `df['time'].dt.strftime("%A, %B %d, %Y %I:%M:%S")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `df.apply`:

```
In [200]: from datetime import datetime

In [203]: df['time'] = df['time'].apply(lambda x: datetime.fromtimestamp(x).strftime("%A, %B %d, %Y %I:%M:%S"))

In [204]: df
Out[204]: 
                                   time
0        Friday, July 28, 2045 01:28:20
1       Tuesday, July 18, 2017 10:21:15
2  Wednesday, January 11, 2192 03:33:45
3    Wednesday, April 15, 2009 12:42:21
4       Friday, March 20, 2009 11:37:11
```